# Uploading and Deserializing protobuf data in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

I have a requirement to send protobuf data to an AWS Lambda written in Node.js. 
I am experimenting with a "Hello World" example where I serialize and deserialize a Person messge.
Example:
person.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Person {
    required int32 id = 1;
    required string name = 2;
    optional string email = 3;
}
```

Using Node.js and the package protobufjs I can generate the code from the proto file and serialize and deserialize a Person object to a file:

```
let person = personProto.Person.create();
person.id = 42;
person.name = 'Fred';
person.email = "fred@foo.com";
console.log("Person BEFORE Serialze=" + JSON.stringify(person1,null,2));

// Serialize
let buffer = personProtos.Person.encode(person1).finish();
console.log(buffer);
fs.writeFileSync("person.pb", buffer, "binary");

// Deserialize
let bufferFromFile = fs.readFileSync("person.pb");
let decodedPerson = personProtos.Person.decode(bufferFromFile);
console.log("Decoded Person=\n" + JSON.stringify(decodedPerson,null,2));
```

Output:

```
Person BEFORE Serialize={
  "id": 42,
  "name": "Fred",
  "email": "fred@foo.com"
}
<Buffer 08 2a 12 04 46 72 65 64 1a 0c 66 72 65 64 40 66 6f 6f 2e 63 6f 6d>
Decoded Person=
{
  "id": 42,
  "name": "Fred",
  "email": "fred@foo.com"
}
```

Using Postman, I want to upload the binary protobuf data to an AWS Lambda from the person.pb file and deserialize it in the Lambda.
When I specify the body as "binary" type and specify the person.pb file, the person data shows up in the Lambda event body as:

```
"body": "\b*\u0012\u0004Fred\u001a\ffred@foo.com"
```

It looks like it got transformed into Unicode and encoded?
How can I take the body string value and turn it back into the Node.js buffer:

```
<Buffer 08 2a 12 04 46 72 65 64 1a 0c 66 72 65 64 40 66 6f 6f 2e 63 6f 6d>
```

so that I can deserialize it back to the JSON object in my Lambda code?

I put the generated code from the .proto file into my Lambda so I can call:

```
let bufferFromEvent = event.body;  <== how do I get a buffer from this?
let decodedPerson = personProtos.Person.decode(bufferFromEvent);
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Chris, Did you try var data = new Buffer.from(event.body, 'base64'); 
        var message2 = personProtos.Person.decode(data);

Answer (score 0):

The answer is what Daniel mentioned in the comment below your question. You need to use the [Buffer class](https://nodejs.dev/learn/nodejs-buffers) provided by Node.

Your lambda function will then look something like this.

```
const personProtos = require("./personProtos");

module.exports.handler = async event => {

const buffer = new Buffer.from(event.body);

console.log(personProtos.Person.decode(buffer).toObject());

return {
  statusCode: 200,
  body: "Success"
};
```

};